# Conversion of pig latin regular expression code into Google BigQuery

Tags: regex, apache-pig, bigdata, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert the below Pig Latin regex_extract function into Google BigQuery regular expression. Can someone share their thoughts on this. My Pig Latin code is as below and would like to implement it in the same fashion in Google BigQuery. Please share your valuable inputs if you can. Thank you.

```
**`Pig Latin code :-`**


report = foreach temp generate referrerUrl, 
                               REGEX_EXTRACT(referrerUrl, '(?i)[&\\\\?]referrer=([^&\\\\u003b]+).*', 1)  as referrerUrl_Final,
                               lUrl, 
                           REGEX_EXTRACT(locationUrl, '((?<=[\\\\u003B|&]r=)[^\\\\u003B|&]+)', 1) AS locationUrl_Final
```

Comment: any thoughts people....?

Comment: Maybe there are not many people who know both Latin and BigQuerySQL - maybe you can rephrase your question in terms unrelated to Latin - just explain how your input looks like and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to convert between Pig and BigQuery in this case. Just load your *temp* data into BigQuery as CSV or JSON and use:

```
SELECT
    referrerURL,
    REGEX_EXTRACT(referrerUrl, '(?i)[&\\\\?]referrer=([^&\\\\u003b]+).*') AS referrerUrl_Final,
    lUrl,
    REGEX_EXTRACT(locationUrl, '((?<=[\\\\u003B|&]r=)[^\\\\u003B|&]+)') AS locationUrl_Final
FROM
    [Mydata.Temp]
```

The Regex should be interpreted similarly but perhaps you can share a few lines of data to test? The only difference AFAIK is that BigQuery's REGEX_EXTRACT function doesn't have the match group index parameter.

Comment: Can you share any documentation where I can learn regular expressions easily.. something with examples for each and every topic with a detailed explanation.. I am new to regular expressions and banging my head to learn it... :(